# How to convert an array output [3, 5, 7, 9,....n] to a list in the console 3 5 7 9... n

Tags: java

I am tryign to build a graph using `g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);` and I need to make sure the first int goes in `x1` and `y1` and the next int to go in `x2` and `y2` - and so on.

Here is what I have got so far:

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int x;
int sample = 0;

// convert to image coords and do actual drawing
for (int i = 0; i < subsets.length; i++) {

    sample = (int) subsets[i];

    x = i * Width;

    array.add(x);
    array2.add(sample);
    System.out.println(array2);
    int x1 = (int) (x - 8); // 8 = Width; this sets out the horizontal steps
    int x2 = (int) (x);
    int y1 = (int) (sample - i);// these are the vertical points
    int y2 = (int) (sample);// need to be able to start from the second element in the array for y2!
    System.out.println(y2);
    g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

The output from `System.out.println(array2);` is in the form `[3, 6, 2, 89, 43, 5, 26 etc]`. I want to convert to form:
3
6
2
89
43
5
26
etc going down the screen in the console

At least that's what I think I need to do to be able to make `int y1 = (int) (sample - i);` work.

Any ideas?

These are all great suggestions (below) but actually the point is I needed to join lines to form a graph. Therefore, I really just needed a way to get the next element in the array.

I got some help and found that if I decrement by 1 in the for loop and added it below: `int y2 = (int) (subsets[i+1])`
it works.

New code listing - which works

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int x;
int sample = 0;

// convert to image coords and do actual drawing
for (int i = 0; i < subsets.length; i++) {

    sample = (int) subsets[i];

    x = i * Width;

    array.add(x);
    array2.add(sample);
    System.out.println(array2);
    int x1 = (int) (x - 8); // 8 = Width; this sets out the horizontal steps
    int x2 = (int) (x);
    int y1 = (int) (sample - i);// these are the vertical points
    int y2 = (int) (sample);// need to be able to start from the second element in the array for y2!
    System.out.println(y2);
    g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

Comment: So you want to print them side by side instead of in a new line?

Comment: Basically what I want is when y1 is (sample - i), y 2 is just (sample). In other words, as it builds the graph with i steps it joins each line from the end of one to the beginning of the next. But I can't use (sample - i) incompatible, and i can't use intNext(). I'm stumped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi use Iterator and print your values

```
import java.util.*;
class ArrayTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // kept your code inside for loop
        ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i =0; i<=10 ;i++){
            arrList.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(arrList);

        Iterator itr =arrList.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.print(itr.next()+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here 2 solutions

public class main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("CAC");
        Integer a = 3;
        Integer b = 34;
        Integer c = 23;
        Integer d = 345;
        Integer e = 2346;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(a);list.add(b);list.add(c);list.add(d);list.add(e);list.add(c);
        //OPTION A
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        list.forEach(i -> {

            builder.append(i);
            builder.append(" ");
            });

        System.out.println(builder.toString());
        //OPTION B

        list.forEach(i-> System.out.print(i+" "));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Hello {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    array.add(3);
    array.add(6);
    array.add(2);
    array.add(89);
    array.add(42);
    array.add(5);
    array.add(26);

    System.out.println(array);

    String arrayStr = getString(array);

    System.out.println(arrayStr);
}

private static String getString(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
    String s = array.toString();
    s = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
    return s;
}
```

}

Output:

```
[3, 6, 2, 89, 42, 5, 26]
3, 6, 2, 89, 42, 5, 26
```